# How to automate to make lists in python from the elements of another List

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list X of n number of elements, so I want to generate a list of each element from the list X.

```
X = [ Task_1 , Task_2 , ... ]
for ele in X:
    ele = []
```

Now, if I use the following code, It gives me an error.

```
print(len(Task_1))
Output:
Task_1 is not defined
```

Comment: That is not the way variable assigment works. You really have only `ele` as variable. Either use global variables or a dictionary altogether.

Comment: Can you post a bit more? How have you defined `Task_1`?

Comment: So you want to have an empty list for each element? Or do you want to have lists with every single element? Like `[[Task1], [Task2]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dictionary instead:

```
X = ['Task_1', 'Task_2', 'Task_3']

container = dict()
for item in X:
    container[item] = list()
```

Afterwards, you'll have e.g.

```
container["Task_1"]
```

as a list. The other way would involve `globals()[item] = list()` in the loop but this really messes up your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Although I do not recommend this, but you can :

```
X = ['Task_1', 'Task_2', 'Task_3']

for item in X:
    globals()[item] = []
    
print(Task_1)
print(len(Task_1))

print(Task_2)
print(len(Task_2))
```

You can make a nested list, or dictionary instead.